# Possible memory leak using Handler?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Will this kind of code cause memory leak in Android?

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Runnable myRunnable =new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something here
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 2000);
    }
}
```

In the code above, myRunnable has strong reference to MyActivity, and myRunnable is added to thread message queue. When MyActivity closes, MyActivity instance is still strong referenced by the global message queue, so there may be memory leak here.

Did I understand it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no memory leak. The `Runnable` will be called in 2 seconds and this message will be removed from the `MessageQueue`.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the runnable gets stuck in the message queue?

Comment: I think no. Take a look at the `Looper.loop()` and `MessageQueue.next()` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a possibility that message can be stuck in queue.

If you will have a long-running operation in your MyRunnable that will have activity.finish() system will have no time to remove your message from the queue and it will get executed next time you run your activity (assuming finish() wasn't closing your app completely)

As a good practice to avoid memory leaks try making inner classes static